# Is there always a bijection mapping one element of an infinite set onto another?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, permutations

Let $S$ be an infinite set, and let $s_1$, $s_2$ be any two distinct elements of $S$. Then how to determine whether or not there is always a bijection of $S$ onto itself that maps $s_1$ onto $s_2$?

I know that this does hold true for a non-empty finite set $S$. How to establish the truth or falsity of this assertion in the case of infinite sets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Map $s_1$ onto $s_2$ and $s_2$ onto $s_1$. Map every other element onto itself. This is your required bijection.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can define $$\varphi :\begin{array}{l}S\to S\\x \mapsto \left\{\begin{array}{l}s_1 \text{ if }x = s2\\s_2 \text{ if }x = s1\\ x \text{ if } x \not = s_1 \text{ and }x\not= s2\end{array}\right.\end{array}$$

And it is easy to check that $\phi \circ \phi = \operatorname{Id}_S$ so $\phi$ is bijective.

Comment: It was really easy! How can I miss out on this, I wonder? Thank you anyway.